# A closed form solution for this exponential sum inequality $e^{-Ax} + e^{-Bx} \leq C$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, closed-form

Is there a closed form solution for $e^{-Ax} + e^{-Bx} \leq C$ where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $C\in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: You can approximate solutions, but I’m not sure about exact solutions. If nobody posts anything, I’ll try to write up an approximation.

Comment: In general no. If $\frac BA$ or $\frac AB$ is an integer $\leq 4$, yes.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks, I would be happy with an approximation better than solving the system $e^{-Ax}\leq C/2$ and $e^{-Bx}\leq C/2$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, do you know if there is an approximation that takes into account the ratio $A/B$ ?

Comment: Only if it is $2$, $3$ or $4$. I still work your problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No pressure and thanks ! By the way, what I meant by approximation is in fact a guarantee, in the sense that the "approximation" $\hat{x}$ should be such that if $x\geq \hat{x}$ then $x$ satisfies the inequality. A naive way to do this is to take $\hat{x}=\max\{A^{-1}\log(2/C),  B^{-1}\log(2/C)\}$, but if $A$ and $B$ substantially differ, then this is far from the optimal.

Comment: Still better ! We can consider that we have an explicit non-iterative solution.

Comment: Have a look at my second answer. Much better. Cheers and thanks for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, I shall assume $a >b$.

For the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^{-a x}+e^{-b x}-c$$ the solution is between
$$x_a=\frac{\log \left(\frac{2}{c}\right)}{a} \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_b=\frac{\log \left(\frac{2}{c}\right)}{b}$$

Now, we shall consider the more linear problem of
$$g(x)=\log(e^{-a x}+e^{-b x})-\log(c)$$ for which
$$g'(x)=-\frac{a e^{-a x}+b e^{-b x}}{e^{-a x}+e^{-b x}}\,\, <0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g''(x)=\frac{(a-b)^2 e^{ (a+b)x}}{\left(e^{a x}+e^{b x}\right)^2}\,\,>0$$ Now, one iteration of Newton method will give
$$x'_a=x_a-\frac{g(x_a)}{g'(x_a)}\,\,> \,\,x_a $$

Since $g(a)>0$, by Darboux theorem, since the second derivative is positive, $x'_a$ is an underestimate of the solution $(x'_a < x_{sol})$. A second iteration
$$x''_a=x'_a-\frac{g(x'_a)}{g'(x'_a)}$$ will probably give almost the solution.

Trying for a few values of  $a$ and $b$ for $c=\frac 12$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
a & b & x_a & x_b & x'_a & x''_a & \text{solution} \\
 \pi  & e & 0.441271200 & 0.509989195 & 0.474860563 & 0.474869172 & 
   0.474869172 \\
 2 \pi  & e & 0.220635600 & 0.509989195 & 0.342888065 & 0.348336941 & 
   0.348346335 \\
 \pi  & \frac{e}{2} & 0.441271200 & 1.019978390 & 0.685776130 & 0.696673882 & 
   0.696692669 \\
 2 \pi  & 2 e & 0.220635600 & 0.254994597 & 0.237430282 & 0.237434586 & 
   0.237434586
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

There is one case which is easy to check : $b=\frac a2$. For this case, we have
$$x'_a=\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{2}\right) \log \left(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{2}\right)-3 \sqrt{c}
   \log (c)-2 \sqrt{2} \log (c)-\sqrt{2} \log (2)}{a \left(2
   \sqrt{c}+\sqrt{2}\right)}$$ while $$x_{sol}=\frac{1}{a}\log \left(\frac{2 c+1+\sqrt{4 c+1}}{2 c^2}\right)$$ At this point, the ratio $\frac{x'_a}{x_{sol}}$ does not depend on $a$. It starts at $1$ for $c=0$, goes through a minimum of $0.981671$ around $c=0.05$ and grows up to $0.996795$ for $c=1$.

It seems that a better approximation would be given by the first iterate of the original Halley method. This new estimate write
$$x_{est}=x_a+\frac{2\, g(x_a)\, g'(x_a)}{g(x_a)\, g''(x_a)-2\, g'(x_a)^2}$$ For the four cases given above, it would lead to
$$\{0.474869174,0.348456482,0.696912963,0.237434587\}$$

For the specific case where $b=\frac a2$, the ratio $\frac{x_{est}}{x_{sol}}$ does not depend on $a$. It starts at $1$ for $c=0$, goes through a maximum of $1.00973$ around $c=0.005$ and decreases to $0.999990$ for $c=1$.

A still better approximation would be given by the first iterate of the original Householder method. This new estimate write
$$x_{est}=x_a+\frac{3 \,g(x_a) \left(g(x_a) \,g''(x_a)-2\, g'(x_a)^2\right)}{g(x_a)^2 \,g'''(x_a)+6\, g'(x_a)^3-6 \,g(x_a) \,  g'(x_a)\, g''(x_a)}$$

For the four cases given above, it would lead to
$$\{0.474869172,0.348390812,0.696781624,0.237434586\}$$

For the specific case where $b=\frac a2$, the ratio $\frac{x_{est}}{x_{sol}}$ starts at $1$ for $c=0$, goes through a maximum of $1.00014$ around $c=0.155$ and decreases to $0.999990$ for $c=1$

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, assume $A > B > 0$ and $0 < C \le 1$. Let $p = \frac{B}{A} \in (0, 1)$.
Let $a = C^{p-1}$. Let $u = \frac{1}{C}\mathrm{e}^{-Ax}$.
We need to solve the equation $u + a u^p = 1$ which admits an infinite series solution (see [1])
$$u = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(pk+1)a^k (-1)^k}{\Gamma((p-1)k+2) k!}.$$
Thus, the solution of $\mathrm{e}^{-Ax} + \mathrm{e}^{-Bx} = C$ is given by
$$x = - \frac{\ln C}{A} -\frac{1}{A}\ln \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(pk+1)a^k(-1)^k}{\Gamma((p-1)k+2) k!}\right).
\tag{1}$$

For example, $A = \sqrt{5}, B = \sqrt{2}$, $C = \frac{2}{3}$,
(1) gives $x \approx 0.619497866$.

*Reference*

[1] Nikos Bagis, Solution of Polynomial Equations with Nested Radicals, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1948.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You have better to recast the equation into a symmetric form, by putting
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  s = \left( {A + B} \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  d = \left( {A - B} \right)/2 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad 
\left\{ \matrix{
  A = s + d \hfill \cr 
  B = s - d \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
so as to get
$$
e^{\, - Ax}  + e^{\, - Bx}  = e^{\, - sx} \left( {e^{\, - dx}  + e^{\,dx} } \right)
 = 2e^{\, - sx} \cosh (dx)
$$
and so
$$
\cosh (dx) \le {C \over 2}e^{\,sx} 
$$

Then you can perform on this the various approximation processes already indicated.

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add another answer instead of adding to the previous one which is already too long.*

Instead of the previous starting point, let us use
$$x_0=\frac{2\log \left(\frac{2}{c}\right)}{a+b} $$ which is obtained by the first iteration of Newton method starting at $x=0$. By Darboux theorem, this is an underestimate of the solution; its advantage is that it takes into account both $a$ and $b$.

The results for the previous four cases ($x_1$ being the first iterate of Newton method starting at $x_0$).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
a & b & x_0 & x_1 &   \text{solution} \\
 \pi    & e & 0.473148142 & 0.474869150 &  0.474869172 \\
 2 \pi  & e & 0.308015202 & 0.347822293 &  0.348346335 \\
 \pi  & \frac{e}{2} & 0.616030405 & 0.695644586 &    0.696692669 \\
 2 \pi  & 2 e & 0.236574071 & 0.237434575 &    0.237434586
\end{array}
\right)$$ The results are much better.

For the case where $b=\frac a2$, the ratio $\frac {x_1}{x_{sol}}$  starts at $1$ for $c=0$, goes through a minimum of $0.996777$ around $c=0.04$ and grows up to $0.999935$ for $c=1$. Much better again.

For the same case, using one iteration of Halley method, the ratio $\frac {x_1}{x_{sol}}$  starts at $1$ for $c=0$, goes through a maximum of $1.00091$ around $c=0.01$ and grows up to $1$ for $c=1$. Much better again.

For the same case, using one iteration of Householer method, the ratio $\frac {x_1}{x_{sol}}$  starts at $1$ for $c=0$, goes through a maximum of $1.000001$ around $c=0.21$ and grows up to $1$ for $c=1$. Much better again.